# Entity Framework (Code First) - How to clone an entity without foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I would like to clone an entity and associate the copy with another object. I've written the following code:

```
var entity = context.Entry(someObject);
entity.State = EntityState.Added;
anotherObject.History.Add(entity.Entity);
```

The problem is that the code doesn't clean foreign keys of the copy, so there are many redundant connections in the database. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching and detaching objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/bb896271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx